# Update all table dropdown list items on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a button to the column when clicked would set all other dropdown items on the current page to the selection made.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/zmbagh9h/)

```
<select class="select2 select2-offscreen" id="id[0]" name="id[0]">
<option value="not received">Not Received</option>
<option value="received">Received</option>
</select>

<select class="select2 select2-offscreen" id="id[1]" name="id[1]">
<option value="not received">Not Received</option>
<option value="received">Received</option>
</select>

<select class="select2 select2-offscreen" id="id[2]" name="id[2]">
<option value="not received">Not Received</option>
<option value="received">Received</option>
</select>

<button class="go-btn" type="submit">Update All</button>
```

JS:

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {

      $("select option").each(function() {
          //how to update the dropdow?
      });   
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with "the selection made"? I'm not sure of what you want

Comment: "selection made" meaning that if the user select "not received" and click on the button then all the dropdowlist should be selected as "not received" and same for the "received" and user clicks on the button then all the dropdownlist should changed to "received" hope this is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/zmbagh9h/3/

```
var lastSelectedValue = 'not received';

$('select').change(function() {
    lastSelectedValue = this.value;
});

$('.go-btn').click(function() {
    $('select').val(lastSelectedValue);
});
```